# Highcharts: how to export several charts from the browser?

Tags: highcharts

I have a page and there are four line charts on it. By having

```
exporting: {
    enabled: false
}
```

I am able to see a Highcharts-generated export dropdown with options such as Download as PDF on each chart. These export options do not involve any access to the server. This is a pure client-side solution.

I wonder whether there is any way to use Javascript  in the browser that allows me to export all charts on the page in a single PDF document?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: How about [FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#export-multiple) ? ;)

Comment: Pawel, "I am able to see a Highcharts-generated export dropdown with options such as Download as PDF on each chart. These export options do not involve any access to the server. This is a pure client-side solution."-- is this correct?

Comment: It is not - Highcharts exporting feature requires external server. My comment was about rendering multiple charts in one pdf/jpeg/png file, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I hate to be the one to break this to you but one clarification needs to be made, the default export options aren't really pure client-side. They leverage [highcharts' own exporting server](http://export.highcharts.com), one can override the exporting server's url using the [`exporting.url`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.url) configuration option

> ```
> url:                            String
> The URL for the server module converting the SVG string to an image format. 
> By default this points to Highslide Software's free web service. Defaults to http://export.highcharts.com.
> ```

You may want to read their [disclaimer & privacy statement](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/privacy-disclaimer) & read more about the export module [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview)

You can consider [setting up your own exporting server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server), and override the export function to send SVG of all the charts on your page and do the stitching on the server side and send back the image.

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: [{
                text: 'Export All Charts',
                onclick: function() {
                    var allCharts=Highcharts.charts;
                    var svgArray=[];
                    for(var i=0;i<Highcharts.charts.length;i++){
                        svgArray[]=Highcharts.charts[i].getSVG();
                    }     
                    // ... Post svgArray to your exporting server                        
                }                    
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Having said that, modern browsers do support saving content of HTML5 canvas elements, check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/PDnmQ/) that uses [canvg](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/) library to export a single chart. *P.S. This isn't the default behavior of highcharts*